# How to work out if a point is behind the field of view

Tags: java, geometry

So I'm rendering points in 3D space. To find their X position on the screen, I'm using this math:

```
    double sin = Math.sin(viewPointRotX);
    double cos = Math.cos(viewPointRotX);
    double xx = x - viewPointX;
    double zz = z - viewPointZ;
    double rotx = xx * cos - zz * sin;
    double rotz = zz * cos + xx * sin;
    double xpix = (rotx / rotz * height + width / 2);
```

I'm doing a similar process for Y.

This works fine, but points can render as if they were in front of the camera when they are actually behind it.

How can I work out using the data I've got whether a given point is in front of or behind the camera?

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of all the variables.

Comment: You should avoid using sin for a variable name since it is also the name of a function. Maybe call is sineX and cosX. In fact, your code would be more readable if you just deleted the sin and cos variables.

Answer (score 0):

We can tell if a point is in front or behind a camera by comparing coordinates with a little 3D coordinate geometry.

Consider a very simple example: The camera is located at (0,0,0) and pointed straight up. That would mean every point with a positive Z coordinate is "in front" of the camera. Now, we could get more complicated and account for the fact that the field of view of a camera is really a cone with a particular angle.

For instance, if the camera has a 90 degree field of view (45 degrees in both directions of the way it is facing), then we can handle this with some linear math. In 2D space, again with camera at the origin facing up, the field of view would be bound by the lines y = x and y = -x (or all points within y = |x|).
For 3D space, take the line y = x and spin it around the z-axis. We now have the cone:
    `z = x*x + y*y`, so if

```
 if(z < x*x + y*y && z>0) 
    then the point is in front of the camera and within the field of view.
```

If the camera is not at the origin, we can just translate the coordinate system so that it is and then run the calculation above. If the viewing angle is not 90 degrees, then we need to trace out some line y = mx (where `m = Math.tan(viewAngle/2)` ) and spin this line about the z-axis to get the light cone.

Answer (score 0):

The way it looks like you are doing this is transforming the point coordinates so that they are aligned with and relative to the view.

If you do this the right way then you can just check that the rotated z-value is positive and greater than the distance from the focal-point to the "lens".

Find the view direction vector:
`V = (cos(a)sin(b), sin(a)sin(b), cos(b))`, where a and b are the camera's rotation angles.

Project the offset vector `(xx, yy, zz)` onto the view direction vector, and find the magnitude, giving the distance along the camera's view axis of the point:

`distance = xx * cos(a)sin(b) + yy * sin(a)sin(b) + zz * cos(b)`

Now just check that `distance > focalLength`.

This should work but you have to be careful to set everything up right. You might have to use a different calculation to find the view direction vector depending on how you are representing the camera's orientation.